# Dynamically created input field using jquery is disabled

Tags: jquery, html

I am working on a dynamic form in which I need to create a dynamic input field on the press of a button. Here is the JQuery code:

```
$(this).find(".inner").html(html_ + "<input type='text' class='TB' id='" + TxtID + "' />");
```

This is the created DOM markup:

```
<input type="text" class="TB" id="S0Q0_TB0"/>
```

This input field is working in Chrome and Safari (Enabled for edit), but it seems to be disabled in Opera, Firefox and IE 9.

Couldnt find a relevant question in the KB. Need a quick solution

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Does any other code make it disabled? You code does not have anything to make it disabled.

Comment: throw in an extra line to enable it?

Comment: The code is fine (though we don't what `html_` is or if `TxtID` is unique or not). So if you have no other info to give us, you won't get any (good\helpful) answers.You see you already got two answers that won't help you a bit...

Comment: @xdazz: No, nothing is making it disabled

Comment: try assigning a `value` attribute to the input. i couldn't reproduce it based on the stripped code, it seems something other than the input code is interfering (e.g. the `html_`, the `TxtID` variable).

Comment: @Venomal So are you able to make a demo to demonstrate the problem?

Comment: @TeunPronk: Already did that, doesnt help.
Its working in Chrome/Safari

Comment: @gdoron: html_ is the previous html of the parent div, it does not interfere with this input field in any way. As for TxtID, you can see id="S0Q0_TB0", txtID is S0Q0_TB0...which basically is the control ID created dynamically.

Comment: @xdazz: Let me see what I can come up with in jsfiddle

Comment: please provide a full example, or better yet, create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo.

Comment: Alytrem posted a snippet which is what I also made.
His snippet works on my browsers which means that its something to do with the code. But what amuses me is that it works in Chrome/Safari :/

Comment: @EliranMalka: Assigning a value, eg: value='0' shows that value in the textbox but I cannot change it in (O/FF/IE), works in (CR/SF) though.

Comment: Thank you everyone.

Sadly, I couldnt get a solution.

Comment: Hello people, I finally found out what was bugging the code yesterday.
Well, since im making a form builder, therefore it has a JqueryUI sortable in it. To stop panel selection, I was using $('#controlID').disableSelection(); which was blocking textbox selection inside every panel.

Thank you everyone for your help once again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it on firefox and Internet Explorer, and it works.
http://jsfiddle.net/mDDPW/2/

Are you sure it's not a side effect for somewhere else in your code ?

Comment: Your snippet is spot on but in my project the created input field is disabled in Opera/FF/IE.

Cant figure out why...but it works in Chrome/Safari

Comment: Couldnt find an answer yet but ill take your effort into consideration.

Thanks

Comment: $.disableSelection(); was the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use append instead of .html

you are also appending but this is very easy to implement..

or if i am understanding your problem then any issue related to browser compatibility..
give browser compatibility..

like this->

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=7" />
```

or try this>>

```
 jQuery('#mainField').find('tr:last').before("<tr><td colspan='3'>&nbsp;</td></tr ><tr><td></td><td align='center'></td><td></td></tr>");
                                                                        jQuery('#mainField').find('tr:last').prev().find('td:nth-child(1)').append(newField);
                                                                        jQuery('#mainField').find('tr:last').prev().find('td:nth-child(2)').append(newField2);
                                                                        jQuery('#mainField').find('tr:last').prev().find('td:nth-child(3)').append(newField3);
```

Comment: this is **bad** practice, user agent meta tags should not be used as permanent solution.

Comment: Cant append, the html structure will get broken.

P.S: I am making a form builder, in which controls are being dragged/dropped on a div where they get created.